# Grub help, Windows not loading

Tags: grub2, windows-7

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7508074/

In the grub menu Windows has two options: sdb1 and sdb2, neither actually do the whole "loading windows" thing. Rather, they both give me a purple screen. I've waited for a few minutes on both so I don’t think this is it just taking a while to load but it never does. Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Boot-Repairs advanced options to choose Windows and sdb to reinstall a Windows boot loader into sdb. Then see if you can boot Windows by selecting Windows in BIOS or one time boot key like f12 but varies by vendor. Did you leave Windows hibernated or does it need chkdsk? Grub really only boots working Windows.

Comment: Should I install grub onto sda instead? I can get windows to boot like this (i assume i was supposed to install a mbr to sdb targeting windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Follow the steps given here. I'm sure it'll fix it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment if you have more questions.

Comment: Yea, the recommended boot option is what is giving me this problem.

Comment: So did it work or not? Because you accepted the answer.